# How come "From" address is not showing in web3.eth.filter?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm trying to figure out how to track the activity of users of my dapp and have a "history" page for them.

For this purpose I decided to set events and track them using web3.eth.filter

This works you can see in this image there is 1 topic showing corresponding to my event. It's a hash but it's my even.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZzXx.png

It's not showing the from address though. How am i supposed to know which user activated the event without it?

I thought it was possible to know the from address using eth.filter because when I use it from random addresses from etherscan, I'm seeing multiple topics and one of them is the from address.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPVEx.png

This is a screenshot of this random transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x20d783d6813e27c3083609228acbcb88b3a508533c101a6393489a82a40564e4

You can see the from address is in one of the topics. How can I get that?

The first screenshot I'm using remix and testrpc.

The second screenshot I'm using metamask's injected web3 inside chrome console and mainnet with a random etherscan address.

```
// This is my contract

contract Test {

    event event1(uint id);
    event event2(string name);
    uint id = 1;

    function buy() public payable {

        event1(id);
        event2('testing');
        id++;

    }

}

// This is what I get when I do web3.eth.filter in remix on testrpc
// The topics are not showing the event values, 
// they are showing keccak256(event1(uint)) without the values.

null[
  {
    "logIndex": 0,
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "transactionHash": "0x81979a998ae284933bb890585020692aad9dfa27bf6b8e6425aa2c9affcdfd43",
    "blockHash": "0x5c1f608098236c1eba26b53c872cf379cd3e82079330b2d06d40c6ce4df5811b",
    "blockNumber": 2,
    "address": "0x71ea15737ce3f92e205e3a3dad0263e344d53f24",
    "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
    "topics": [
      "0x84e603adc6c5752ecafe165459551af7ba28bb2e6a2bfacc9ccb8f0ae12c76e6"
    ],
    "type": "mined"
  },
  {
    "logIndex": 1,
    "transactionIndex": 0,
    "transactionHash": "0x81979a998ae284933bb890585020692aad9dfa27bf6b8e6425aa2c9affcdfd43",
    "blockHash": "0x5c1f608098236c1eba26b53c872cf379cd3e82079330b2d06d40c6ce4df5811b",
    "blockNumber": 2,
    "address": "0x71ea15737ce3f92e205e3a3dad0263e344d53f24",
    "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000774657374696e6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "topics": [
      "0xd61481a11e5449d64f97e1edf49aec06a9ff79cef718c30115a331a73ae49cb4"
    ],
    "type": "mined"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events don't really have a "from" address. There are three addresses I can think of that you might mean:

1. The address of the contract that logged the event.
2. The address of `msg.sender` at the time the event was logged.
3. The address of the externally owned account that initiated the transaction in which the event was logged.

(1) is the `address` field of the log object you receive.

(2) is not generally available, but many events explicitly include it as part of their data. (E.g., for the contract you mentioned, there's a `Transfer` event declared as `event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);`.)

(3) is available by following the transaction hash, which is again part of the log object you receive. Each transaction records its originating "from" address.

Comment: How come I can see the value of the Transfer event using eth.filter? Isn't it supposed to be a hash of "Transfer(address,address,uint256)" ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What value? And why *wouldn't* you be able to see it? All logs are publicly visible.

Comment: I thought the topics are hashes of the event name + argument types. Like "Keccak(Transfer(address,address,uint256))", this is what I see when I do we3.eth.filter in remix on testrpc. I'm not seeing the actually values passed to my event. I'm seeing literally only "Keccak(event1(uint))" in "topics"

Comment: Yes, the first topic is that hash. Did you mean to ask why *can't* you see some value? Please share your code so someone can help.

Comment: The arguments to the event are encoded into the `data` field. Arguments are only `topics` if they're `indexed`, which yours are not.